# A network-related error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a web application in which i am interacting with the sql server database.
The application is uploaded in the IIS server.

It was working fine but all of a sudden when i started my system I got the following error.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I have checked the sql configuration tool, server is running. The stack trace I am getting is given below.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

```
**Source Error:**
```

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
Stack Trace:
```

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +6675958
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +688
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +6702504
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) +219
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6704598
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6705099
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions) +610
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1049
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +74
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) +6707667
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) +78
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2192
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1012
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   +6712291
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +152
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +229
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +292
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +420
>          System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +280
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +3581727
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +176
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +51
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +146
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +36
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
>          System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +4297

My firewall is off so there is no issue of that. Please note I have sql server 2008 and 2012 both installed in my system. So for that I have upgraded the 2008 to service pack 3.
Can anyone please tell me why all of a sudden I got this issue?

And how can I resolve it?

Comment: there are many posts about this question,did you search?like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error

Comment: yes ..my configuration are as per the recommendations only

Comment: Check this **[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18060818/3030434)**

Comment: I have checked and my settings are as per the recommendations only...still getting the error

Comment: Please add the `connectionString`

Comment: What is your connectionstring, did you connect to the sql server with exact server,user and password that is mentioned in the connectionstring?